# Group of order $p^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

$G$ is a group of order $p^2$, $p$ is a prime. If $Z(G)=p$ then $G/Z(G)$ has order $p$ and $G$ is cyclic. Why $G$ is cyclic?

Is it related to the Lagrange Theorem?
Actually, I have no idea about it.
Thanks

Comment: I know |G/Z(G)| = p....

Comment: Have you seen the proof that G is abelian? From there, it will follow that G is cyclic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result is false since the conclusion says that $G$ is cyclic of order $p^2$ so the center of $G$ is $G$ and the cardinal of $G$ is different of $p$ which is supposed to be the cardinal of $Z(G)$.

Comment: I wouldn't say the result is false but rather the given set of condition is never fully fulfilled: the quotient $\;G/Z(G)\;$ can never be cyclic non-trivial, and thus since the assumption is always false, the whole claim is true, even if after "then" it was written that whales are birds that live on the Moon.

Answer (score 1):

$Z(G)$ cant be of order $p$ since every group of order $p^2$ is abelian.
For if $G$ is not abelian this implies that $|G|>|N(a)|>|Z(G)|$ ,$N(a)$ is the normalizer of an element for every a in G.
But if $|Z(G)|=p$ this leaves that $|N(a)|$ can only be $p^2$ because of the inequality above, and sice order of a subgroup divides order of the group.
But if $|N(a)|=p^2=|G|$..this means the group is abelian.
Hece for a group of order $p^2$ you can never get a strict inequality between these three.
So the group has to be abelian.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not well formed. By definition, the center of a group is as follows:

$$\mathcal{Z}(G) = \{g \in G | xg = gx\ \forall x \in G \}$$

We see that in an abelian group, $\mathcal{Z}(G) = G$. All cyclic groups are abelian (this is trivial, but if you want I can give a proof) and therefore $\mathcal{Z}(G) = G$ for $G$ cyclic. But here $|\mathcal{Z}(G)| \ne |G|$. This means the group cannot be abelian and therefore cannot be cyclic.